# Do we have $1_{\{\max_{k\leq n-1}X_{k}\leq \lambda_{n}\}}(\omega)\to 1_{\{\max_{k\leq \infty}X_{k}\leq \infty\}}(\omega)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For $X_{n}$ independent, $\lambda_{n}\uparrow \infty$ and $\sum P(X_{n}>\lambda_{n})<\infty $ do we have the pointwise limit

$1_{\{\max_{k\leq n-1}X_{k}\leq \lambda_{n}\}}(\omega)\to 1_{\{\max_{k\leq \infty}X_{k}\leq \infty\}}(\omega)$?

This is in trying to prove

$P(\max_{k\leq n}X_{k}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)=P(X_{n}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)$.

I think a possible counterexample is some alternating $X_{n}$ s.t.

$1_{\{\max_{k\leq n-1}X_{k}\leq \lambda_{n}\}}(\omega)=0$ but

$1_{\{\max_{k\leq n}X_{k}\leq \lambda_{n+1}\}}(\omega)=1$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but you can use Borel-Cantelli Lemma to get $P(\limsup X_n > \lambda_n) = 0$.

Comment: No. Note that $ 1_{\{\max_{k\leq \infty}X_{k}\leq \infty\}}(\omega)=1$ for every $\omega$ (omitting the fact that $k\le\infty$ should read $k<\infty$ since there is no $X_\infty$ here). The proof that $P(\max_{k\leq n}X_{k}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)=P(X_{n}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)$ is quite unrelated. You are asked to prove that $(\max_{k\leq n}X_{k}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)=(X_{n}\geq \lambda_{n}~i.o.)$, which is not a stochastic result and is true for every increasing sequence $(\lambda_n)$.